# Getting the value of button (vuejs)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

i want to get the value of the button when click i already add a method. but whenever i click theres nothing. the value not passing. can anyone help me? Thank you.

Here is the code:

```
<button
class="button buttonvalue"
v-for="(p,index) in buttonvalue"
:key="index"
@click="webcamSendRequestButton($event)"
>{{p}}</button>
```

Method:

```
  methods: {
    webcamSendRequestButton: function(e) {
    // const buttonValue = e.target.value;
    // console.log(e.target.value)
    alert(e.target.value);
    }
  }
```

DATA (Json) of button value

array data: small,medium,large

this.buttonvalue= this.item[0].buttonvalue.split(',');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get value button value you can either bind a `:value` attribute first like:

```
<button
  class="button buttonvalue"
  v-for="(p,index) in buttonvalue"
  :key="index"
  @click="webcamSendRequestButton($event)"
  :value="p"
>{{p}}</button>
```

Then `e.target.value` will work fine.

---

Or, if you don't want to add another attribute, then you can simply use:

```
methods: {
  webcamSendRequestButton(e) {
     console.log(e.target.textContent)
  }
}
```

instead of using `e.target.value`.

---

Or, if the value `p` is required, then you can simply pass that to click handler like:

```
@click="webcamSendRequestButton(p)"
```

and then access it like:

```
methods: {
  webcamSendRequestButton(buttonvalue) {
     console.log(buttonvalue)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply need to pass a value of `p`, for example then you would write:

`@click="webcamSendRequestButton(p)"`

then in your method:

```
  methods: {
    webcamSendRequestButton(val) {
       alert(val);
    }
  }
```

I am assuming that `buttonvalue` is some kind of `array` that you are looping through.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes it did helppp.. just try now. Thank you very muchhhh!!!!

Comment: Glad to hear. Enjoy Vue!